# Linked list node memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, malloc

In creating a linked list we make a node structure and it consists of both data and a pointer to the next node. Later when we make a function to append elements onto the linked list, we make a temporary node to store the inputted data.

Let’s consider the following program-

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node* link;
}
struct node* root=NULL;
void main(append)
{
  struct node* temp;
  temp= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node))
  .....
}
```

**My first question set:**

In line 11, why do we need to mention `(struct node*)` before the malloc function?

What is the significance of that?

**My second question set:**

If we are making a doubly linked list which would have a node structure consisting of 2 pointers (for next and previous node), would we also initialize a pointer (for traversing the list) of the struct node type?

Is there a different way to initialize the pointer in that case?

Comment: Who told you you need that? It is even strongly discouraged. In general, never use unnecessary casts, they will eventually drop on your head one day. If you got that from your C book, get a better one. If from some obscure youtube vvideo, blog or online-tutorial: Get a good C book.

Comment: Note that if you use a C++ compiler to compile C code, that cast would be necessary.  It isn't necessary in C that's only compiled by C compilers.  Also note [Do I cast the result of `malloc()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Instead `temp= malloc(sizeof *temp);`  Easy - is it not?

Answer (score 1):

The significance is to make bugs in your program,

The malloc will return `void*` and when you assign to your `struct somthing*` it will convert automaticlly.

Comment: The cast makes the program compatible with C++ compilers at least.

Comment: But the question was about c-code, and not about c code which needs to be compatible with every language

Comment: But the question was why are we meantioning the type of the pointer in the malloc function when we have already declared it as type 'struct node*' ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply don't cast the result of `malloc` as it returns `void*` . There is one fine explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

A better solution might be :

```
struct node *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

Comment: But the question was why are we  meantioning the type of the pointer in the malloc function when we have already declared it as type 'struct node*' ?

Comment: And the answer is still the same , its bad habit . No need to cast the result of malloc. Whoever wrote the code thought that there was a need for that cast which is simply illogical.

Answer (score 0):

> why do we need to mention '(struct node*)' before the malloc function,
>   what is the significance of that?

By writing `(struct node*)` before the `malloc` function, you are type-casting the return value to the specified type. The cast here is optional and [often frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

> if we are making a doubly linked list which would have a node
>   structure consisting of 2 pointers(...

When making a doubly linked list, you should declare something like:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
};
```

You can allocate space for a node by using the `malloc` function. The `next` and `previous` pointers are again pointers to `struct node`s. Call `malloc` again to allocate space for the `next` element. For the first node, the `previous` should be `NULL` and for the last node, `next` should be `NULL`. [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/76931/doubly-linked-list-code-in-c) is one implementation.

Comment: Normally the `append` function would allocate a new node in `next` and have the new node point in `prev` to the current (last) node. No storage would be allocated for `prev`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Ahh right. Maybe I was not paying attention when I wrote that. Edited.

Comment: But the question was why are we meantioning the type of the pointer in the malloc function when we have already declared it as type 'struct node*' ?

Comment: @AdityaVinodKumar As I have mentioned in my answer, the cast is optional and often discouraged. Please read the page I have linked. Click on "often frowned upon" in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is the because the return type of malloc is void*. (struct node*) is a cast using which you tell the compiler that you want to treat the value returned by malloc as a pointer to struct node.

For double linked list you can use,

```
struct node
      {
       int data;
       struct node *next,*prev;
       };

int main()
{
   struct node *new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

malloc returns the void pointer(can be checked and verified at the header ), and so the type casting is necessary while assigning it to the other type of variable.

Request you to read at the link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong. Your reference is about integer promotions and conversion of numerical types, not about pointers. @0decimal0's answer is correct. See that reference.

Comment: I was making a point that return type of malloc is not struct node* type and hence it should be typecasted to the pointer type of struct node

Comment: "`malloc` _will return_ `void*` _and when you assign to your_ `struct somthing*` _it will convert automaticlly._" (See other answers.)